# Artifactory validation

Tags: validation, artifactory

From time to time we upgrade our artifactory or apply patches to it. As a process we make these changes in our pre-production environment first before promoting the changes to production artifactory. When we perform these changes, we get many complaints from the users regarding performance issues or their builds broke etc.

So I wanted to know what all validations we should run through in our pre-production artifactory environment so that we are sure things will not break when these changes are applied to production artifactory environment?

I appreciate if any one has ideas around recommended best practices.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a great question.

Artifactory is a powerful repository manager that serves as a central hub for managing software artifacts. When upgrading Artifactory, it's important to ensure that the new version is installed and configured correctly to avoid any issues that may arise due to inconsistencies or misconfigurations.

1. Verify the Artifactory version:
   Check the Artifactory version to ensure that it matches the version you intended to upgrade to.
   $ curl -uadmin:password https://<artifactory_url>/api/system/version
2. Verify services are running:
   Check that all the services that should be running are up and running. You can do this by checking the status of the Artifactory service in UI. We can also get the same information by running one of the following commands on the Artifactory server/pod by getting the topology health on the internal(8046)/external(8082) Router port.
   $ curl -uadmin:password http://localhost:8082/router/api/v1/topology/health
   $ curl -uadmin:password http://localhost:8046/router/api/v1/topology/health
3. Test the connectivity:
   Test the connectivity between Artifactory and your development tools to ensure that the upgraded Artifactory is still accessible and functioning correctly.
4. Verify User Access and Authentication:
   Test user access and authentication to ensure that users(i.e internal, LDAP, SAML, etc) can still log in and access the system.
5. Verify that all custom configurations have been preserved:
   Ensure that all custom configurations have been preserved after the upgrade.
6. Verify repositories and artifacts:
   Verify that all the repositories and artifacts that were present before the upgrade are still present and accessible. We can do this by browsing the repositories in the Artifactory UI or by running the following command in the terminal:
   $ curl -uadmin:password https://<artifactory_url>/<repository_name>/path/to/artifact
   Also, capture the [storage summary](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/get-storage-summary-info) of the Artifactory before the
   upgrade activity and compare it against it after the upgrade by running
   the following REST API call.
   $ curl -uadmin:password https:///artifactory/api/storageinfo
7. Verify user permissions:
   Verify that all the user permissions that were present before the upgrade are still intact and working as expected. You may check the permissions of a few admin and non-admin users manually or create sample post-upgrade validation builds to read/deploy the artifacts on random Artifactory repositories.
8. Verify plugin compatibility:
   Check the compatibility of any installed plugins with the upgraded Artifactory version. These plugin files were present under the $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/plugins directory. You may check the Artifactory logs to see if there are any issues with plugin loading during the startup.
9. Verify backups:
   Verify that any backup processes you have in place are still working as expected and that you can restore Artifactory from a backup if needed.
10. Verify performance:
    Verify that Artifactory is performing as expected and that there are no issues with response times, throughput, or other performance metrics.
11. Verify integration with other systems:
    Check that any integrations with other systems, such as CI/CD pipelines, are still working as expected.
12. Verify log files:
    Check the Artifactory system logs to ensure that there are no errors or warnings related to the upgrade. You can find the logs in the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/var/log/ directory.
13. Verify Artifactory Configuration:
    Review the configuration settings to ensure that all settings and configurations are still valid and have not been changed or lost during the upgrade process.
14. Perform load testing: Perform some load testing to ensure that Artifactory can handle the expected workload.

It is important to perform these validations after upgrading Artifactory to ensure that your Artifactory instance is functioning properly and to avoid any issues or downtime.

Comment: Hi Tatarao Vana, To your point nuuber "10 Verify performance: " regarding "Verify that Artifactory is performing as expected and that there are no issues with response times, throughput, or other performance metrics." Can you please suggest what tool I can use to do load/performance testing on the identified critical repositories of Artifactory? What type of test cases should I use? Can you share sample scripts that can auto generate load etc. I appreciate any details around it. Thanks

Comment: Rahul, you can write a sample script to create a repository, generate random artifacts by iterating them in a loop and upload it parallelly for a while, delete them later, etc to check how the system is behaving for a high load of requests. I do not have any script in hand to share, however, you can develop one based on the kind of artifacts you have and the number of requests the Artifactory instance handles at a given moment.